# Write uploaded file by chunks in an async context

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a Python async function receiving a [`django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/files/uploads/) from an Django API endpoint, as well as from a Django form.

Once this function/coroutine is launched, it needs to write the file, and since the files are large [Django suggests to use `UploadedFile.chunks()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/files/uploads/) method to do so.
So I have a classical sync method to write the file by chunks to a destination path, looking like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

from django.core.files.uploadedfile import TemporaryUploadedFile


def write_file(file: TemporaryUploadedFile, destination: Path) -> None:
    with open(destination, "wb+") as out:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            out.write(chunk)
```

As said, it is called from an async context, using `asgiref.sync.sync_to_async`. The main function logic looks like this:

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from pathlib import Path

from django.core.files.uploadedfile import TemporaryUploadedFile


async def process_submission(file: TemporaryUploadedFile) -> None:
    ... do stuff ...
    await sync_to_async(write_file)(file=file, destination=Path("/my_path.mp4"))
    ... do other stuff ...
```

...but I get the error `ValueError: read of closed file` for the line `for chunk in file.chunks()`.
The `write_file()` function was working fine when called from a sync context, though.
I believe it might be related to the fact that the file is a stream, but I'm not really sure on what's happening. Any idea on why and how to solve that?

Comment: I don't have an environment now to reproduce it, but can you be sure that the error comes from `file.chunks()` and not from `out.write(chunk)`? The fact that `file` is a stream has nothing to do with it. What is the rest of your  `async def process_submission`? You might close the `file` right after calling `await sync_to_async(write_file)(file=file, destination=Path("/my_path.mp4"))`.

Comment: The error happens on the line `await sync_to_async(write_file)(file=file, destination=Path("/my_path.mp4"))` -> `for chunk in file.chunks():`.

In `process_submission` there is no logic to close the file, as I'm using `with open()` and not `open()`.

Comment: Added a few edits to the question to help, thanks to the questions from @foobarna.